# Integral $\int_0^{\infty} te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I want to compute $\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_0^{x}te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt=\int_0^{\infty} te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt$. To do this I have thought that since I have an illimitate interval and in $0$ the function $te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}$ is not definite I can write:
$$\int_0^{\infty} te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt=\int_0^{1} te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt+\int_1^{\infty} te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt$$
The second integral is divergent since $te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\sim t(1-\frac{1}{t^2})=t-\frac{1}{t}$. So:
$$\int_1^{\infty} te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt=\int_1^{\infty} t\, dt-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{t}\, dt$$
and since the secon integral is divergent I have that $\int_1^{\infty} te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt$ is divergent. So the overall integral is divergent whatever is the behaviour of $\int_0^{1} te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt$. 
But really I have to understand its behaviour:
the problem is in $0$ where the function is not defined but really the limit as $t$ goes to $0$ is finite, so how can I treat this integral?

Comment: Thanks! What's $\int_0^1 te^{\frac{-1}{t^2}}$? I don't how treat it!

Comment: The question needs some editing.  Also, $te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}$ has a finite limit when $t$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Yes, this integral is finite (because as $t\to 0$, $te^{-1/t^2}\to 0$). When you say you want to understand its behavior, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: If you are familiar with gamma functions, why don't you approach the integral that way...although if I'm right, you may end up with a $\Gamma (-1)$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ah ok so if I have a function that is convergent the integral cannto be divergent right? Sorry for the stupid question but I am only starting studying improper integral

Comment: @MisterMak what kind of edit you suggest?

Comment: Just for your interest, with the change of integration variables $s=1/t^2$, your integral can be written in terms of the upper incomplete gamma function: $$
\int_0^x {te^{ - 1/t^2 } dt}  =  - \frac{1}{2}\int_{1/x^2 }^{ + \infty } {s^{ - 2} e^{ - s} ds}  =  - \frac{1}{2}\Gamma \left( { - 1,\frac{1}{{x^2 }}} \right).
$$ You can see that the integrand has a non-integrable singularity at $s=0$ (it behaves like $1/s^2$).

Answer (score 1):

For all $t \ge 1$, we trivially have $$t e^{-1/t^2} \ge t e^{-1/1^2} = t/e,$$ so the integral on $[0,\infty)$ is divergent.  For $0 < t < 1$, $$0 < te^{-1/t^2} < t/e,$$ thus $$\lim_{t \to 0^+} t e^{-1/t^2} = 0.$$  Together, this establishes $$\int_{t=0}^n t e^{-1/t^2} \, dt > \int_{t=1}^n t/e \, dt = \frac{n^2 - 1}{2e}$$ for all $n > 1$, and in fact the asymptotic expansion is $$\frac{n^2}{2} - \log n + \frac{\gamma - 1}{2} - \frac{1}{4n^2} + \frac{1}{24n^4} + O(n^{-6}).$$

Comment: So if the function is convergent cannot be possible that the integral is divergent?

Comment: Moreover the passages done by me to prove that $\int_1^\infty$ is divergent are not right?

Comment: Can you help me please? i have not completely understood

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt$$ Make one integration by parts with $u=e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}$ and you have
$$I=\frac{1}{2} t^2\, e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}} - \int \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}}{t}\,dt$$ Now, let $t^2=\frac{1}{y}$
$$\int \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}}{t}\,dt=-\frac 12 \int \frac{e^{-y}}{ y}\,dy=-\frac{1}{2}\text{Ei}(-y)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.

So, back to $t$,
$$I=\int te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt=\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)+e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}} t^2\right)$$
$$J=\int_0^x te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\, dt=\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} x^2\right)$$ and the asymptotics  (already given by @heropup) is
$$J=\frac {\gamma-1}2 +\frac{x^2}{2}-\log (x)-\frac{1}{4 x^2}+\frac{1}{24 x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$